# Duplicate objects in ArrayList are references to a single one?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

I have an `ArrayList` that has some objects that I defined in it. Based on some criteria, I want to copy some of the objects from the first list to the second list (which starts empty), but these objects that I copy could be copied several times ( can be duplicates ).

To simplify for an example let's say my second list contains only 2 objects that are duplicates. Objects a and b.

If I modify something in object a, will that modification also appear on object b ? It is just a reference that is passed or it's a copy of an object?

```
for( int i = 0; i < Selected.size(); i++)
            {
                double chance = random.nextInt(100);
                chance = chance/100;
                if( chance >= constCrossover ) 
                {
                    Cross.add(Selected.get(i)); 
                     //here i add items that might be duplicates
                }
            }
```

I will make further modifications in the Cross list and i don't want duplicate objects to interact with eachcother.

Comment: use sets instead of list for the second collection if the major concern is duplication. Also, check out the clone api for reference

Comment: what i have understood from u r question is you want to copy some object from one array list to another array list . object could be duplicated and when you mead change in first array list it should be replicated to another array list is it correct

Comment: As Jon Skeet pointed out, there are references. You should perform deep cloning for the objects you want to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changes to a single object in the second list will be reflected on all of it's duplicates. To avoid this you might need to clone your object, i.e. via a copy constructor.

Answer (score 7):

It's *always* a reference. The value of an expression, the value in an array etc is *always* either a reference or a primitive value. Nothing will copy an object implicitly - you'd have to do that explicitly.

(As an aside, you should follow Java naming conventions - `Selected` and `Cross` should probably be `selected` and `cross`.)

Answer (score 2):

It is always a reference that is copied to the new array list, to avoid this implement clone in your object and in the second arraylist add the cloned object.

Answer (score 1):

dont look at objects.. look at references.. if both "a" and "b" references point to the same object, then if you change the object via "a", then when "b" accesses it, the changes made by "a" can be seen..

Answer (score 0):

It will be a reference so changes in one will be visible in the other. You'd have to

I think it's better to use the `foreach` mode of for-loop in Java.

```
for (YourObject yourObject : selected) {
    if(yourObjectShouldBeAdded) {
        cross.add(new YourObject(yourObject));    //initialize new copy in any way needed
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to use Guava libraries: [Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) and [Iterables](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html). In this way:

```
List<YourObject> cross = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(selected, new Predicate<YourObject>() {
                              @Override
                              public boolean apply(YourObject input) {
                                  if(yourObjectShouldBeAdded) {
                                      return true;
                                  }
                               }
                          }));
```

I think in your case, the condition `yourObjectShouldBeAdded` refers to a random number `chance` being greater than a constant `constCrossover`. You can simply substitute that.